# ElasticSearch most-frequent terms over time

Tags: elasticsearch

We're researching technology options that will allow us to conduct a most-frequently-occurring terms query over millions of documents.  We have a little experience with an older version of ES but are by no means experts.  It's not clear to me from reading the ES documentation whether it can do this.

Imagine a data set of millions of tweets from 10,000 distinct people.  We wish to do the following:

*For each one of the 10,000 tweeters,* what are the top-10 most frequently occurring terms that they've tweeted over the last hour, the last day, the last year?

Likewise and similarly, if each tweet record contains an array of the mentioned hashtags, calculate the same statistics for most-commonly occurring hashtags.

If one option is to do these calculations on-demand only when the end-user asks for them via the user interface, then that's an option also.  We only expect a small percentage of these calculations to actually be used.

Can this be done in an efficient manner on ES?  Can you provide a rough example so that we can know how to use the API accordingly?  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood you correctly you want to get top terms by users

```
POST /tweets/tweet
{
"text": "We're researching technology",
"user": 1,
"hasttags": ["hastag", "hastag1"]

}

POST /tweets/tweet
{
"text": "We have a little experience with an older version of ES #hastag",
"user": 1,
"hasttags": ["hastag", "hastag2"]
}



POST /tweets/tweet
{
"text": "For each one of the 10,000 tweeters, what are the top-10 most #hastag",
"user": 2,
"hasttags": ["hastag", "hastag3"]
}


POST /tweets/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "user": [
        "1"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "terms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "text",
            "size": 10
          }
        },
        "hasttags": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "hasttags",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is example because problem here would be that its limited to 10 users only, since in ES 1.4 there is no way to do paging over aggregation. Also on the other hand you can specify size to 10,000 but you need to try and see how it works on real data and your cluster machine since it will demand more memory. I am building most used search term in my search engine where i am setting 1000 for aggregation and it works pretty cool.

TODO: 
Look to [stop words](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-stopwords.html) to exclude terms like "a" "in" so on

Comment: Thanks we will explore this!  Note I made an edit afterwards saying that we would only need statistics like this when the end-user of the application requests them.  That could potentially simplify the problem, I don't know.

Comment: @David You updated querstion about has tag so in few mins i will update my answer

Comment: @David i have updated my answer, if i understood you correctly  "when the end-user asks for them" means that you will have limited amount of users where you want to get statistics  if thats right then i see my updated question